# Error: System.NullReferenceException error in Selenium with NUnit

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, c#, nunit, exception

[image][image: Errors Generated On Running Code][image: Error - Unexpected Character]I'm getting following error at verification stage:

```
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in nunit.framework.dll

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
```

code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Login_Val_Test_Do_Not_Use
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //Instantiate Firefox Driver
            //Go to CV Library Website
            var driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.cv-library.co.uk/");

            //Wait for web element to become visible
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(15000);

            //Click on Login button
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='home-nav-right']/a[1]")).Click();

            //Verification that specified page opens
            var loggedInHeader = driver.FindElement(By.Id("cand-login-tabs"));
            Assert.IsTrue(loggedInHeader.Displayed, "Unable to access page");

            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please try this instead? driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='home-nav-right']/a[1]")).Click();

Comment: At what line of code are you getting the error.

Comment: @Yu Zhang - I get an error message on using the XPath. Please, see screen shot.

Comment: @ Alok -  Assert.IsTrue(loggedInHeader.Displayed, "Unable to access page");

Answer (score 1):

The following should work. I've used the class name for the login button instead of using XPath (seems more appropriate here) + always use explicit waits **never** Thread.sleep!

```
//Instantiate Firefox Driver
//Go to CV Library Website
var driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.cv-library.co.uk/");

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
IWebElement loginButton = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.ClassName("nav-login")));

loginButton.Click();

//Verification that specified page opens
var loggedInHeader = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("cand-login-tabs")));
Assert.IsTrue(loggedInHeader.Displayed, "Unable to access page");
```

Comment: @GMcCannon - Many thanks for your response. But the code generated errors. I have options that I can use to  fix it. But, wanted to run it by you 1st.. Many Thanks.

Comment: Sorry about that. Fixed a couple of typos but I don't have access to VS right now. If it's still giving you errors, let me know what they are and I'll do my best to figure it out.

Comment: Oh just saw you added a screenshot with the errors. The two 'By' errors were caused by the typos I've already fixed. The reason you are getting the 'driver' error is because you've left out the first four lines of code - They were from your original code btw.

Comment: Did this work or not?

Comment: @ NotInventedHere, apologies for replying rather late. Thanks you very much for the assistance. 

I get the same error. I have "googled the error". It appears the compiler is not "seeing" the value in question. It appears as not "null" to it ?

Here: 

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120781/how-do-i-fix-this-error-an-unhandled-exception-of-type-system-nullreferenceexc

2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5261250/an-exception-of-type-system-nullreferenceexception-occurred-in-myproject-dll-b

I am still researching this issue.  I really appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Strange, it's working fine for me. Have you tried putting a breakpoint on that assert line and running in debug mode? Can you post your current code? The last screenshot you posted covers the most important bit with a popup :) Oh and you might want to tidy up your question. It's getting a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting the error on the assertion line, it's exactly what the message tells you - you're getting a null reference.  Often this is due to the fact that your `FindElement()` fails, so then when you try to access one of the methods or properties (e.g. `click()` or `Displayed`), you get a null reference error since the object isn't what you think it is (it's null because the element wasn't found).

For debugging, you can just add some checks after each of the `FindElement()` calls to verify an element was found, but really, the stack trace/console logging should point you to the exact line that failed.